# How can I download an image over HTTP with unicode letters in URL?

Tags: php, http, curl, download

How can I download the following URL (image) using PHP: `http://www.delo.si/assets/media/picture/20121228/POLITIČNI05 tomi lombar.jpg?rev=2`?

The problem is that PHP somehow doesn't support unicode letters in the URL (see the `Č` letter in there?). I've tried using both `file_get_contents` and cURL, none work. Bellow is my non-working code.

**`file_get_contents`:**

```
$url = "http://www.delo.si/assets/media/picture/20121228/POLITIČNI05 tomi lombar.jpg?rev=2";
$stream_context = array('http' => array( 
    'method'=>"GET", 
    'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" 
));
$image_contents = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($stream_context));
file_put_contents("image.jpg", $image_contents);
```

**cURL:**

```
$url = "http://www.delo.si/assets/media/picture/20121228/POLITIČNI05 tomi lombar.jpg?rev=2";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen('image.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

**What "doesn't work" means:**
What I meant with "doesn't work is that I get a different picture downloaded than the one I get if I paste the URL in my browser. This site apparently has a fallback picture set up, so if the picture doesn't exist, you get the default one.

Comment: Did you try using `urlencode` over that URL before sending it to the server?

Comment: @vectorialpx: You might want to actually answer the question, or someone else is helpfully going to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) around the image name. So:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$img = 'http://www.delo.si/assets/media/picture/20121228/' . rawurlencode('POLITIČNI05 tomi lombar').'.jpg?rev=2';
readfile($img);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you think it should, try it and paste the code.

Comment: This was because of the spaces in the URL. urlencode() changes spaces to `+` - I have swapped it for rawurlencode() and this does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use utf8_encode for quoting unicode characters

```
$url = "http://www.delo.si/assets/media/picture/20121228/POLITIČNI05 tomi lombar.jpg?rev=2";

$url = utf8_encode(str_replace(' ','%20',$url));
```